# Trying to query XML Data - node has a space in it

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to learn how to work with xml files and data in SQL Server and I'm trying to query an xml file but nothing is returned.

Here is the xml data:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <Report xmlns="AdmissionsByPCP" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="AdmissionsByPCP" xsi:schemaLocation="AdmissionsByPCP http://10.xxx.x.xx/ReportServer_NameofReportServer?%2FHl%20C%20Syst%20Reports%2health%2FAdmissBy&rs%3ACommand=Render&rs%3AFormat=XML&rs%3ASessionID=h0iz5ijxgt2vdl45g3pjfs45&rc%3ASchema=True">
        <Tablix2>
            <Details_Collection>
            <Details PCPCarrier="DoctorsName">
            <Subreport1>
            <Report Name="PCPAdmitSubReport">
                <Tablix5 Textbox5="79">
                    <Details_Collection>
                        <Details Textbox37="Discharge Dx Code: ICDCode" Textbox89="Admit Dx Code: ICDCode" LOS="4" DischargeDate="07/10/2017" AdmitDate="07/06/2017" Hospital="Hospital Name" MemberName="Name" DOB="1/1/2019" AdmissionType="Inpatient" MemberNo="12345" Auth="321*I" Status="Close" AdmissionID="00001" LobName="Medicare" CarrierName="CarrierName"/>
</Details></Details_Collection></Tablix5></Report></Subreport1></Details></Details_Collection></Tablix2></Report>
```

Here is the query I'm using:

```
Declare @XMLData as XML
Set @XMLData=(
Select bulkcolumn
FROM OPENROWSET (Bulk '\Directory\AdmissionsByPCP.xml', 
                Single_Blob) a)

Select
    @XMLData.value('(/Root/Report/Tablix2/Detail_Collections/DetailsPCPCarrier) [1]', 'varchar(max)') PCP
```

The query returns null and I don't know why.  Is it because there is a space in the node (`<Details PCPCarrier>`) and if so how do I work around that?

Comment: "Is it because there is a space in the node ()"... where exactly are you referring to there being a space?

Comment: is that even valid xml?

Comment: What are all those dashes doing in the XML? And it seems like most opened tags aren't closed. I.e. that XML doesn't appear to be valid after all.

Comment: I cleaned up the XML a touch.  I made assumptions with the schema.  Can you now update the XML to make it complete?  At least close the tags so we get a better feeling of your full schema.

Comment: @Tanner The "()" was Stack Overflow's broken markdown parser deciding that the XML tag was HTML and not escaping it for display in the browser; I have added backticks to make it display properly.

Comment: I added the closing tags at the end.  It was a large file so I only grabbed the first few line.  Hopefully I did it correctly.  I am not very familiar with xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood how XML works. This is the node you are looking for:

```
<Details PCPCarrier="DoctorsName">
```

This is not a node called `Details PCPCarrier`; it is a node called `Details` with an attribute called `PCPCarrier`.

So the XPath to select it would be:

```
/Root/Report/Tablix2/Detail_Collections/Details
```

Or, if you want to specifically filter by the `PCPCarrier` attribute existing:

```
/Root/Report/Tablix2/Detail_Collections/Details[@PCPCarrier]
```

Or, to get the value of the attribute itself:

```
/Root/Report/Tablix2/Detail_Collections/Details/@PCPCarrier
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, I'm learning xml.  I tried that query and got a null result.  Does the path have to start with /Root or is that a variable?

Comment: I figured it out but could not have with out your help.  I added the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

IMSoP pointed me in the right direction and I figured out the rest myself.

I also needed to add this:

```
With XMLNAMESPACES (Default 'AdmissionsByPCP')
```

So the query looks like this:

```
Declare @XMLData as XML
Set @XMLData=(
Select *
FROM OPENROWSET (Bulk '\\Directory\AdmissionsByPCP.xml', 
                Single_Clob) a );
With XMLNAMESPACES (Default 'AdmissionsByPCP')
Select
    @XMLData.value('(/Report/Tablix2/Details_Collection/Details/@PCPCarrier)
```

[1]', 'varchar(max)')